# Headers for the kernel were not found

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, offline, guest-additions

Im trying to install the guest additions for the virtualbox.

my main operating system is `xubuntu` and the OS on the VB is `ubuntu 14.04`

so I have the iso file on CD (the computer is offline), and when I run the command `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` I get the error

> The headers for the current running kernel were not found.

I tried:

1. run `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-headers` and I can see that all linux headers are installed
2. installed the `dkms` for the compatibility of the kernel
3. installed `linux-headers-generic`
4. installed `build-essential`

but I keep get that message..